# How to change domain type and VNC listen address with libvirt-php?

Tags: php, virtual-machine, virtualization, kvm, libvirt

I'm currently developing a snippet of code to create a libvirt KVM domain.  Currently, the script is in working condition, but I'm unsatisfied with the way that I'm having to do things.  As it stands, I'm having to load the domain XML using the PHP bindings, manually change it, then undefine and redefine the domain, all to change the domain type, and VNC address.  I would like to know if there are any better alternatives to the way that I'm doing this below (The code that I'm not happy with is on lines 5 & 6).  I feel like the PHP binding documentation is extremely lacking, which is why I haven't found a solution to this problem yet.  I know that I should be able to do what I'm wanting to do because virt-manager can do it.

```
$vnc = "PGdyYXBoaWNzIHR5cGU9J3ZuYycgcG9ydD0nLTEnIGF1dG9wb3J0PSd5ZXMnIGxpc3Rlbj0nMC4wLjAuMCcgcGFzc3dkPSdfX1BBU1NfXyc+CiAgICAgIDxsaXN0ZW4gdHlwZT0nYWRkcmVzcycgYWRkcmVzcz0nMC4wLjAuMCcvPgogICAgPC9ncmFwaGljcz4="; // VNC config (base64)
$dom = libvirt_domain_lookup_by_name($c, $command['parameters']['name']); // Get domain resource
setBridge($dom, $command['parameters']['networks'][0]['mac']); // Replace network configuration with an interface bridge
setISO($dom, "/var/lib/libvirt/ISOs/Win7Pro.iso"); // Set the CD-ROM ISO
$xml = libvirt_domain_get_xml_desc($dom, null); // Get XML
domain_change_xml($c, $dom, str_ireplace("<domain type='qemu'>", "<domain type='kvm'>", str_ireplace("<graphics type='vnc' port='-1' autoport='yes'/>", str_ireplace("__PASS__", rand(10000000, 99999999), base64_decode($vnc)), $xml))); // Replace domain type and graphics block
libvirt_domain_create($dom); // Start the domain

function setBridge($dom, $mac) {
    libvirt_domain_update_device($dom, "<interface type='bridge'><mac address=".escapeshellarg($mac)."/><source bridge='br0'/><model type='e1000'/></interface>", VIR_DOMAIN_DEVICE_MODIFY_CONFIG);
}

function setISO($dom, $iso) {
    libvirt_domain_update_device($dom, "<disk type='file' device='cdrom'><driver name='qemu' type='raw'/><source file=".escapeshellarg($iso)."/><target dev='hdc' bus='ide'/><readonly/></disk>", VIR_DOMAIN_DEVICE_MODIFY_CONFIG);
}
```